# Show Modal Update Progress While Full Post back using PostbackTrigger

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Javascript for Begin and End request Handler to Show Modal Progress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $find('ModalProg').show();
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $find('ModalProg').hide();
        if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
            args.set_errorHandled(true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Button Inside Update Panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3"  runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                            onclick="btnProdMgmtMain_Save_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Modal Progress :

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalProg" BehaviorID="ModalProg" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateProgress1"
    PopupControlID="UpdateProgress1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel3">
            <ProgressTemplate>
            Updating!
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I must declare the button as postbacktrigger control because I am flushing report on click...

I try to add OnclientClick to button and Show Progress but not seems to be a better solution to Hide the Modal progress.

I see some similar posts here but the answers are not related to my problem..

P.S : I try to use body onsubmit event to load the Update Progress Modal popup but no hope at all

Modal Update Progress is not showing after i tried these things

Comment: i did not understand what is the problem ? the modal is not appear ?

Comment: Do you have try `$find('<%=ModalProg.ClientID%>').show();` ?

Comment: yes I tried already but no help